# Rails 3 f.select set up for use in jQuery submitted form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, select

I'm using jQuery to submit `f.select` on a search form using Ransack. For the longest time I didn't know why the Ransack search form I was using wasn't working, and it turned down it had to do with the set-up of my `f.select`. I was using:

```
<%= f.select :profile_subject_cont, options_for_select([['Select', 'nil'], ['Arts']... ['Vocational']], @q) %>
```

Instead of:

```
<%= f.select :profile_subject_cont, options_for_select([['Select', ''], ['Arts']... ['Vocational']], @q) %>
```

What I'd like to do with my `f.select` is two-fold:

1. When I select an option in my `f.select`, my form is submitted and the option that was submitted as a param is shown as the selected option. Currently what happens is the option is submitted as a param, but the `f.select` resets when the form is submitted, leaving "Select" as the selected value.
2. If I can get #1 to work, I'd like the selection of "Select" to reset the search_form's param for `profile_subject`. It looks like currently the form submits with params when the option is selected, but when the results are rendered the `profile_subject` params go back to nothing. (That's probably why I can't get post back to work.

Does anyone know how I can get this to work? It has plagued me too long. Here's the jQuery I'm using to submit the form just in case:

```
$(function(){
    $('select').live('change',function() {
        $(this).closest('form#index').submit();
    });
});
```